# Uploading Image from html to mysql database using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, upload

I am tying to store an image url in mysql using jsp but facing an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException plz help

my html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image upload</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
   <form name="form1" id="form1" action="UploadImage.jsp" method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--<input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield1" value="ok">-->
<h1 align="center">Image Upload</h1>
 <hr color="pink" width="50%" size="5%" align="center">
 <br>
  <table border="5" align="center" bordercolor="grey">    

  <tr>
    <td>Name Of The Image</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="n1" size="50" placeholder="abc"></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Size</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="s1" size="10" placeholder="100mb"></td>

 </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="t1" size="20" placeholder="eg: pdf" ></td>

   </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td><input type="date" name="d1" size="15" ></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>File Upload :</td>
  <td>

  <input type="file"  name="file"  ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center">

     <input type="submit" value="INSERT" class="btn">
  </td>

  </tr> 
  </table>
   </form>

   </body>
  </html>
```

my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.*" %>
 <%@ page language="java"  errorPage="" %>
 <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
 <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*"%>
 <%@page import="java.util.Iterator,java.util.List" %>
 <%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*,
  org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*,
  org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
  <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

  <%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
  <%
   String name="";
    String size="";
    String type="";
    String date="";
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List  items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator iter = items.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
     FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

        if (item.isFormField()) {

          if(item.getFieldName().equals("n1"))
                {
                    name=item.getString();
                }
          if(item.getFieldName().equals("s1"))
                {
                    size=item.getString();
                }
          if(item.getFieldName().equals("t1"))
                {
                    type=item.getString();
                }
          if(item.getFieldName().equals("d1"))
                {
                    date=item.getString();
                }


         }
      }

    String saveFile="";
    String contentType = request.getContentType();
     if((contentType != null)&&(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") 
      >= 0))
      {
     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
      int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
        byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
      int byteRead = 0;
      int totalBytesRead = 0;
     while(totalBytesRead < formDataLength)
        {
     byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
      totalBytesRead += byteRead;
     }
     String file = new String(dataBytes);
     saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
     saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
      saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 
     1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
     int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
     String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 
       1,contentType.length());
     int pos;
     pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
      pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
       pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
       pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
     int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
     int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
     int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
      File ff = new File("D:/Upload/"+saveFile);
     FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);
      fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
     fileOut.flush();
     fileOut.close();


    %>
       <%
       Connection connection = null;

       PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
   try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     connection = 
     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/s36", 
     "root", "legend");
     psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into 
     image(name,size,type,DOU,url) values(?,?,?,?,?)");

     psmnt.setString(1,name);
     psmnt.setString(2,size);
    psmnt.setString(3,type);
    psmnt.setString(4,date);
    psmnt.setString(5,ff.getPath());
    int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
    if(s>0)
      {
      out.println("ssjhdsj");
      response.sendRedirect("ImgSuccess.html");

      }
     else
       {

      }
     }
    catch(Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
       }
    %>
```

error:

exception:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

The database i m using is mysql
What am i doing wrong here??
plz help!!! ThanK you!!

Comment: Now if you had written this using servlets, you would have nice usuable stacktrace - JSP is for presentation

Comment: and why do you do `pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
      pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
       pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
       pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;` ?

Comment: i ssly have no idea about the "pos=file.indexOf()" thing.. i found his code alrdy from this site itself!!...This code is working wen image is uploaded alone but not with other input parameters with it!

Answer (score 1):

My money would be on this line:

```
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
```

Because when you did this:

```
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
```

You could have easily wound up with a negative number for `boundaryLocation`.

That having been said, there are a few other locations in the program I could see this happening depending on the input.  I am assuming this is some sort of assignment or you are just learning but even so you should take the advice in the comment on your question and get this in a form where you could get a usable stack trace.

One thing I am certain of is it has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: Yes this is a project of mine...Thank u for ur help..SO wat do i need to do??

Comment: It has been a long time since I worked with jsp but I would suggest this to learn how to debug it

[Debuggin jsp](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_debugging.htm)

Comment: even servlet will do...i m just looking for a code to upload an image on a folder and then store the url of the image in database!!